# Please provide me with a regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

Please help me find a regular expression to parse the data like this:

```
'EBB112'  '0 23923 12272 7'    Carrots            'C' 'O' 'A' 'B' 'C'  '12/128ml'     '$9.65'       '$0.80'

'EBB211'  '0 23923 12266 6'   'Vegetables & Turkey'    'C' 'O' 'A' 'B' 'C'     '12/128ml'     '$9.65'       '$0.80'
```

I have these 11 fields (shown in single quotes) and I need to parse them field by field and save them into a .csv file.Have about more then 3000 such lines.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Quote: *You have a problem and decide to solve it with a regular expression. Now you have two...*

Comment: are the fields seperated by a tab, or spaces?  looks like you could just do a string newstr = oldstr.Replace("  " /*two spaces*/, ",");...

Comment: They are separated by spaces and they don't contain Single quotes..

Comment: how many spaces separate them?  Only 1, or more than 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend not trying to figure out a regex yourself - try to use an appropriate library to handle stuff like that.

Take a good look at [FileHelpers](http://www.filehelpers.com) - it's a great, **free** C# library to handle any kind of delimited (e.g. CSV, tab-delimited) or fixed-width import files.

You basically define the structure of your import file in a class that represents the data (something like this: I don't know what your field are called - so I'm just guessing :-)

```
using System;
using FileHelpers;

namespace ReadDataFromFile
{
    [DelimitedRecord(" ")] 
    public class DataClass
    {
        [FieldQuoted('\'', QuoteMode.OptionalForBoth)]
        public string EbbField;
        [FieldQuoted('\'', QuoteMode.OptionalForBoth)]
        public string CompoundField;
        [FieldQuoted('\'', QuoteMode.OptionalForBoth)]
        public string VegiField;
        [FieldQuoted('\'', QuoteMode.OptionalForBoth)]
        public string C1Field;
        [FieldQuoted('\'', QuoteMode.OptionalForBoth)]
        public string O1Field;
        [FieldQuoted('\'', QuoteMode.OptionalForBoth)]
        public string A1Field;
        [FieldQuoted('\'', QuoteMode.OptionalForBoth)]
        public string B1Field;
        [FieldQuoted('\'', QuoteMode.OptionalForBoth)]
        public string C2Field;
        [FieldQuoted('\'', QuoteMode.OptionalForBoth)]
        public string MlField;
        [FieldQuoted('\'', QuoteMode.OptionalForBoth)]
        public string DollarField1;
        [FieldQuoted('\'', QuoteMode.OptionalForBoth)]
        public string DollarField2;
    }
}
```

and then the FileHelpers library handles all the rest for you:

```
using FileHelpers;

...
  FileHelperEngine engine = new FileHelperEngine(typeof(DataClass)); 
  DataClass[] res = engine.ReadFile(@"D:\test.data") as DataClass[];
```

Now, your array `res` contains one entry for each line in your data file - pretty slick!

No fuss, no muss, no regexes.

Comment: This looks pretty good ..I am going to try this one...Thanks marc_s

Answer (score 0):

you don't need regex for that as far as i can see ...

split into lines ... strip the first, and the last single quote, and split by this string "' '"

//edit:

ah... those whitspaces weren't there some time ago ;-)

the line with "Carrots" (the field without single quotes) makes this a bit painfull

lets try this regex as a split token on all lines:

/'\W+'/

ignore empty fields in the results, and mark all lines that don't produce 11 non-empty fields for further processing ... you will need another regex for those ...

Comment: That's not the case , I have some more line except these lines ...Plz Help me to get a regular expression to extract these data from text file..

Answer (score 0):

Use [text2re](http://txt2re.com/), a free web-based "regex by example" generator. This will help you varieties of regular expression to test.

Answer (score 0):

Start with this

```
system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches(Str,@""\'(.*?)\'"))
```

That will grab all the stuff between single quotes but you need to look at each match and this won't handle weird cases with nested delimiters or other such nonsense.

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string instead by `' '`.

```
var array = Regex.Split(line.Substring(1, line.Length - 2), "' '");
```

I've removed the first and the last chars because they will not be removed by the split method.

Answer (score 0):

('?.*'?)\s*('?.*'?)\s*('?.*'?)\s*('?.*'?)\s*('?.*'?)\s*('?.*'?)\s*('?.*'?)\s*('?.*'?)\s*('?.*'?)\s*('?.*'?)\s*('?.*'?)

I think basicly ('?.*'?) means a group of characters that might start with ' and end with '
 and then any number of \s* or simply speaking whitespaces

I might be wrong thou

Answer (score 0):

Try this(this won't handle single quotes within data):

```
string[] entries = 
    { 
        "'EBB112'        '0 23923 12272 7'    'Carrots'            'C' 'O' 'A' 'B' 'C'     '12/128ml'     '$9.65'       '$0.80'",
        "'EBB211'  '0 23923 12266 6'   'Vegetables & Turkey'    'C' 'O' 'A' 'B' 'C'     '12/128ml'     '$9.65'       '$0.80' "
    };

    var newEntries = entries.Select(a=> Regex.Replace(a, "'\\s+'", "','")).ToList();

    newEntries.ForEach(
        a=> <YOUR_FILE_STREAM>.WriteLine(a)
    );
```